# how to restrict my android wifi connect to only one access point?

Tags: wi-fi

I like to restrict my android device's wi-fi connect to one and only one access point. The attempt to connect to any other access points should be prevented.

Is it possible to check the SSID value of access point in wi-fi driver and allow connection to only one particular SSID value?

Comment: Just a try, remove write permission of wpa_supplicant.conf file after saving your preffered ssid. I havent tried yet.

Answer (score 3):

By default Android will not connect to an access point unless it is in your list of "Remembered" networks.  A network is remembered automatically the first time you connect to it.  The solution is to open Settings -> Wi-Fi then select each Wi-Fi access point and click "Forget".  This will remove it from the list of "Remebered" networks.  From this point forward, Android will notify you that networks are available, but will not connect without solicitation.

If you're asking for security reasons, there is no security mechanism for white listing Wi-Fi networks.  Android has no parental controls, if that's what you're after.

Comment: Well, it won't connect to a *network* unless it's in the list. It will connect to any access point on that network.